# Option disabledDates from bootstrap datetimepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using the [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) for my calendar. My code looks like this:

```
var sundaysDisabled = [
  moment("17/12/2017"),
  moment("7/1/2018"),
  moment("14/1/2018"),
  moment("21/1/2018"),
  moment("28/1/2018"),
  moment("4/2/2018")
];

$("#form_dateTakeout").datetimepicker({
  inline: true,
  format: 'L',
  daysOfWeekDisabled: daysDisabled,
  disabledDates: sundaysDisabled,
  date: selectDate,
  minDate: tomorrow
});
```

I've found the option `disabledDates` in the [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates).

The problem is I can still select these days, I'm only getting this warning:

[image]

But I think that it can't be the problem, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting *Deprecation Warning* because your date string are not in a recognized format (ISO 8601 or RFC 2822), you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). In your case, you can have something like `moment("17/12/2017", 'D/M/YYYY')`.

To set a default date to the datetimepicker, use [`defaultDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) option instead of `date` (the first is documented while the latter isn't, even if it seems that both work).

Be sure that your [`defaultDate`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate), [minDate](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate), [`disabledDates`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disableddates) and [`daysOfWeekDisabled`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#daysofweekdisabled) are coherent, see also [`useCurrent`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) docs.

Set the `defaultDate` to an enabled date to prevent something like:

> Uncaught Tried 7 times to find a valid date

Here a full example:

```js
var sundaysDisabled = [
  moment("17/12/2017", 'D/M/YYYY'),
  moment("7/1/2018", 'D/M/YYYY'),
  moment("14/1/2018", 'D/M/YYYY'),
  moment("21/1/2018", 'D/M/YYYY'),
  moment("28/1/2018", 'D/M/YYYY'),
  moment("4/2/2018", 'D/M/YYYY')
];

var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'd').startOf('d');
var daysDisabled = [3]; //e.g. disable all wednesday
var selectDate = moment().add(1, 'week').day(2); // e.g. select next tuesday
$("#form_dateTakeout").datetimepicker({
  inline: true,
  format: 'L',
  daysOfWeekDisabled: daysDisabled,
  disabledDates: sundaysDisabled,
  defaultDate: selectDate,
  minDate: tomorrow
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="form_dateTakeout"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `moment()` function usage.

Pay attention:

`moment("17/12/2017").isValid()` `-->` returns **false**

`moment("12/17/2017").isValid()` `-->` returns **true**

Alternatively you can use this format:

`moment("17/12/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid()` `-->` returns **true**

Check here: https://momentjs.com/

Verify on this working CodePen: https://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/PEqYMv

Comment: Then I'm getting this error: Uncaught Tried 7 times to find a valid date

Comment: have you checked the CodePen?